# How to get weakly connected components from a directed boost graph?

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have the following boost directed graph:

```
boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, VertexObjectPtr, EdgeObjectPtr>
```

And I would like to iterate over its weakly connected components without having to do an undirected copy. 
Boost provides a method to compute it for undirected graphs throughout [*connected_components*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html) but it is only valid for undirected graphs. There is also [*strong_components*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/strong_components.html) for directed graphs, but there is no *weak_components* method.

Is there a way to get an undirected view of a graph ? A custom DFS-based approach would work, but I would not like to write custom code for this.